# Is there an elegant way to convert List<Double> into List<Number>?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a function whose arguments are:

```
 myFn(String, List<Number>, List<Number>)
```

The calling function has two objects of List which I want to use as the 2nd and third argument of the function. I get the compilation error:

```
The method myFn(String, List<Number>, List<Number>) in the type MyLib is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<Double>, List<Double>)
```

Is there an easy way to overcome this? Is there an easy way to cast the list of Double into a List of Number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot cast `List<Double>` to a `List<Number>` because the following code would break your `List<Double>`

```
List<Double> list = new List<Double>();
List<Number> list1 = list; // This does not work
list1.add(new Integer(0));
Double d = list.get(0);// Hu-hoh you received an Integer, not a Double!!
List<? extends Number> list2 = list; // This does work
```

What you could do, is change

```
myFn(String, List<Number>, List<Number>)
```

to

```
myFn(String, List<? extends Number>, List<? extends Number>)
```

Answer (score 4):

change myFn definition to `<T extends Number> myFn(String, List<T>, List<T>, Class<T> type)`
and you can call it as `myFn(String, List<Double>, List<Double>, Double.class)`

Comment: I don't see the requirement to add the class to the end of the method.

Comment: You're right it's not necessary. It depends on whether you want to know real type in method body.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the list won't get modified by the method, just use

```
List<Number> unmodifiableView = Collections.unmodifiableList(doubleList);
```

which runs in constant time and returns a view.  It's perfectly type-safe, efficient, and legal -- so long as you know the list won't get modified.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the `myFn` method, then cheating is an option:

```
private <returntype> myFnAdapter(String s , List<Double> l1Double, List<Double> l2Double) {

  // the following lines do create warnings
  // it's safe, because all list items always extend Number.
  List l1TypeErased = l1Double; 
  List<Number> l1Number = l1TypeErased;

  List l2TypeErased = l2Double;
  List<Number> l2Number = l2TypeErased;

  return myFn(s, l1Number, l2Number);
}
```

You should see some warnings, that's all. But we know that we get lists of `Double`s and that all items of those lists extend `Number`, so it won't cause trouble at runtime. Just add a comment to explain the type erasure. It's cheaper then copying all values to new lists.

Comment: Isn't this a bad practice? Yes it works but it also allows to end up with ClassCastException if myFn modified the list

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I added 2 extra lines and now it should be a compiletime error if the signature of `myFn` is changed. Sure, it's pretty ugly (not elegant, as required). It's an adapter for incompatible lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
myFn(String, List<? extends Number>, List<? extends Number>)
```

or call your function with

```
myFn(String, (List) list1, (List) list2); // produces a warning.
```

Comment: Isn't this a bad practice? Yes it works but it also allows to end up with ClassCastException if myFn modified the list

Comment: I am making the assumption that the developer knows that this function can be safely called even if the compiler does not.  I have never see a good case for using `List<Number>` as its next to useless IMHO so its hard for me to imagine what `myFn` does.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast Collections like this. [This Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) gives you the full explanation.

As a solution, where you are calling the method just create a new List with the Double List as a parameter:

```
List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();

myFn(new ArrayList<Number>(doubleList));
```